# How could I go abouts making a functional Submit button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-emulator

I want to add Ratings of 1-5 stars to my project for users to leave feedback within Android Studio, I have added the base code to display the ratings but I don't know how to setup an active submit button to actually relay the feedback to, I just have the submit button displayed.

How could I go abouts creating an active Submit button to when it's pressed it will return back to the user saying their feedback has been submitted instead of it currently just being displayed with no action when pressed.

```
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating_rating_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize=".5" />
        
        <Button
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"/>
        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@+id/submit_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
            android:id="@+id/rating_display_text_View"
            />
```

Comment: Set a click listener to the Button and when it's clicked get rating value from RatingBar by calling getRating() method on it and send it wherever and however you want. Then show a Toast or SnackBar to notify the user. Don't you know how to set click listener and how these widgets work?

Comment: Yeah I haven't setup a click listener before, I just created one though and a review box for if they wanted to leave a review, question is what would I need to make my submit button functional instead of not doing anything? What method would I need to create

Comment: Read this : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button

Comment: I just read it but I don't know where to direct the submission and what to put in for ''//Do something in response to button click'', that's the main bit I can't work out

Comment: Well in that case you should be more specific, for example you want to send feedback through email, in that case you should search for "android Intent to send email". Or you have an API and an online database to store feedbacks and in that case you need to learn android networking, and so on. For these you don't need to ask questions on Stack Overflow because it would be duplicate of many other questions and it gets closed. I know at the beginning it's a little hard but it's actually more helpful in long term if you get used to surf the web and find out things by yourself. Wish you luck ;)

Comment: Is there anyway to just return the feedback inputted to the console to show the submit actually listens and works instead of going through android networking in detail. I just want a basic working submit button

Comment: Yes there is : https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: It shows you how to create log messages in the logcat, in my case I don't see anything from my eyes atleast to where I could call the ID from my submit button and review text ID to call into a method to return a result to what the user inputted into each, in that page I just see ''Log.d(tag, message)'' which  I don't think applies to me.

Comment: You need to have reference to views. Get them either with **findViewById** or **View Binding** and then like I said before use **getRating** method of RatingBar and **getText** of EditText and print the results as a Log. It appears you're not familiar with basics of android framework. Please see [this page](https://developer.android.com/courses), it contains links to lots of free courses and codelabs.

Comment: So I have to create a method for RatingBar with the parameter ratingBar and another one for getText of EditText with parameter review? I don't know what code actually prints the results in the log and that webpage showed an extensive amount of information not related to my project since I just need to display 'Your submission has been submitted' with a reset of the inputted review. Currently my methods are not overriding anything